# Get .df schema timings

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am running a .df file on tables of varying size and would like to gather timings for how long each item (add column, add unique index, etc.) in a .df takes to apply on each of these tables. One approach I have used is to partition the delta by individual items and run them separately, but this as a whole takes longer than running them as one .df and I would like the most accurate timings possible. Is there a feature in openedge such as adding extra logging, outputting results, etc. that would allow me to gather timings on how long these items take to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extract load_df.p from prodict (Here's the KB http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/15884),
you can customize to add your own logging, so it will suit your needs. I'm pretty sure it would be simple to code.

But answering your original question, I can't think of any default extra logging option to give you that kind of information.

Answer (score 1):

If you start your session you use to load you df with

```
-clientlog "c:\tmp\mylog.log" -logentrytypes "4GLTrace" -logginglevel 2
```

then you should get a trace through the code along with time stamps and so on. I've no idea if it will do what you want, but it's worth a try!